# Barcode reader issue

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, keyboard-wedge

right now I am using a barcode reader connected to the computer via usb. The reader in question is an optic one of the brand Alberici, model LT-B001-0010.

I use this reader to scan health cards (ehic), and I would need to save the scan image and save the barcode string.

My problem comes from the fact that the reader in question is not sold with its own software for use and therefore I can not use it as I would like.

I tried to use a couple of software but they were either not functional or were not compatible with the barcode reader.

Although it should simulate a keyboard, the situation is a bit ambiguous because if I open the notepad and scan the ehic the barcode reader does not automatically write it to the text file.

Does anyone have any advice on how I should move? A software that could help me, lines of code, it’s all right as long as it’s functional.

Thank you

R.B.

Comment: According to the manual, the barcode reader does not simulate a keyboard as you suspect. Instead, it creates a virtual serial port. Try a terminal program to verify it. Baud rate is 115,200.

Comment: You’re right about that

Comment: But the question is the same